# Facebook FQL gives error for friends_birthday permission

Tags: facebook, permissions

I am try to execute fql to get permissions for myapp. here is my fql query

```
    SELECT read_friendlists,friends_birthday FROM permissions where uid='.$uid
```

It works fine with app I had created earlier but with newly created app I get following error

"friends_birthday is not a member of the permissions table"

Any Idea what is causing this?

Comment: All `friends_…` permissions have been removed in V 2.0 of Graph API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until April 30 2015 you should still be able to use the v1.0 of the Graph API. As CBroe wrote, the friends_* permission will be removed then.

You should be able to specify the Graph API version you want to use till then as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#calling_from_supported_sdks

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20read_friendlists%2Cfriends_birthday%20FROM%20permissions%20where%20uid%3Dme()
```

works for me if I choose v1.0 as version in the upper right corner's dropdown.

Comment: Okay, and after April 30th what would be the way to access friend's birthdays.  I don't see anything on the Facebook developer's site to provide an alternative...